# I can't connect to any network

Tags: 12.04, broadcom, ethernet

When I plug in the ethernet, 'connection 1' shows under connections, and when I click it, it tries to connect for a while then says 'connection 1: Disconnected'.

My best guess is that I need to install some kind of driver, but I can't without internet. 
I'm on a Dell Inspiron 1501, using Ubuntu 12.04. BTW, it worked with an older version of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you don't need to install driver. The connection link there means, the driver is activated already. I guess, it is more like a cable problem or network problem. Check your cable and/or contact your network provider.

Comment: My other computer connects fine on that cable.